# Apollo Server - didReceiveResponse access the parsedURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

how do I access the async didReceiveResponse(sourceRes, sourceReq)

console.log('sourceReq ----->  ', sourceReq); // output below

[image]

I tried to print out the parsedURL with loggers below
[image]

console.log('  sourceReq passedURL ++++++ > ', sourceReq.passedURL); // is null ??

Headers, method print out OK but not parsedURL

[image]

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Simple answer
[image]

User the URL to parse.

Found the answer here - https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/

[image]